# setuptools finds files, but not functions?

Tags: python, python-3.6, conda, setuptools, packaging

## Background

As a setuptools newb, I am trying to follow the steps in [this video](https://youtu.be/P3dY3uDmnkU?t=151).
(Relevant timestamps are 2:31 and 3:09). My goal is just to get this example to work, but using conda rather than venv. That is, I want to package a simple package, install it locally with pip and use the modules available in that package. The package is successfully found and is importable, but its contents (modules and their functions) are not.

I was unable to find a similar question online. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Below are more details.

## Directory Structure

```
PackageTests
|
|-- README.md
|
|-- prettypackage
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |
|   |-- prettypackage.py
|
|_  setup.py
```

## File Contents

### `__init__.py`

... is empty.

### `prettypackage.py`

```
class PrettyClass():
    def speak(self):
        return "i am so pretty uwu"
```

### `setup.py`

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='prettypackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='Just a beautiful test package, heh',
    packages= ['prettypackage']
)
```

## What I've tried

### In Anaconda Prompt

First, I `cd` to PackageTests. Then:

```
conda create -n package_test
conda activate package_test
conda install -n package_test "python<3.7"

pip install -e .
python
```

### In Python (in Anaconda-Window)

```
import prettypackage
prettypackage.PrettyClass().speak()
```

**Result:**

First line runs fine, second line gives:

`AttributeError: module 'prettypackage' has no attribute 'PrettyClass'`

`dir(prettypackage)` also lists only dunder-variables (`__name__`, `__doc__` etc.).

## Directory Structure after Package Installation

```
PackageTests
|
|-- README.md
|
|-- prettypackage
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |
|   |-- prettypackage.py
|
|-- prettypackage.egg-info
|   |
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   |
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   |
|   |-- top_level.txt
|
|_  setup.py
```

## (New) File Contents

### `dependency_links.txt`

... is empty.

### `PKG-INFO`

```
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: prettypackage
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: Just a beautiful test package, heh
Home-page: UNKNOWN
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: UNKNOWN
Description: UNKNOWN
Platform: UNKNOWN
```

### `SOURCES.txt`

```
README.md
setup.py
prettypackage/__init__.py
prettypackage/prettypackage.py
prettypackage.egg-info/PKG-INFO
prettypackage.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
prettypackage.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
prettypackage.egg-info/top_level.txt
```

### `top_level.txt`

```
prettypackage
```

Thanks again, in advance, for your help!

Comment: Is there a `prettypackage.py` file in the same directory you are trying to test your package installation?

Comment: @jordanm The directory structures given above are both complete, i.e. there are no other files in the PackageTests directory. Edit: One hidden file as an exception: the .idea hidden directory. But it only contains xml and iml files.

Comment: I meant in the current working directory of your shell in which you are typing the command "python". Files in your current working directory come before all other import locations.

Comment: @jordanm I am running "python" in the PackageTests directory. It could at best find the PackageTests/prettypackage/prettypackage.py file. Running python in the prettypackage directory results in expected behavior, since - I assume - the local file is read directly.

Comment: You would need `import prettypackage; prettypackage.prettypackage.PrettyClass().speak()`. And to be more accurate I would rename the file `prettypackage/prettypackage.py` to `prettypackage/prettymodule.py`. So that you wold have `prettypackage.prettymodule.PrettyClass().speak()`.

Comment: @sinoroc Thanks for the reply, I'll try it later. I doubt it will work, however, since `dir(prettypackage)` doesn't list "prettypackage" or anything else that might be useful. As for your other suggestions - I agree; I only used the above naming, since it was used in the talk and I was trying to stick to that code as much as possible (until I get it to work for the first time, at least).

Comment: If `dir(prettypackage)` doesn't show anything then maybe try `import prettypackage.prettypackage` or `from prettypackage import prettypackage` or something similar.